Running sudo command in bash script
I have a db server where I am sshing into and I am running the command sudo -u oracle -H bash and I am able to validate that successfully by doing this manually but I am trying to do the same process using bash script so I defined it in bash file as
script="sudo -u oracle -H bash"
ssh myhostname "${script}" 
cd && sbx1.env
sqlplus / as sysdba

So after running this script it is prompting for fingerprint for authentication and after changing to Oracle user it is not running the below commands starting from cd&&. If I do the same process manually without bash script I am able to validate that command successfully. I also tried to run other commands like creating a file with vim /tmp/SQL.txt and I'm able to validate that successfully but I am not able to runnitbas another user . Any help is very much appreciated!!

Once you exit the remote bash (type exit to do so), your script should do the cd locally and execute the program sbx1.env. Show a screenshot of what you are doing.
